# Obtener día anterior

Tags: php, mysql

Hola a todos estoy tratando de generar una consulta que me cuente los registros del día anterior pero no logro conseguir el resulta, ya que con el query que he tratado de hacerlo me trae la fecha pero lo que necesito es el nombre del día.

Con este código se que se obtiene el nombre del día actual.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish");echo utf8_encode( strftime("%A"));
```

Este código me genera el día anterior, es decir me muestra el resultado de esta manera 15/04/2021 siendo hoy 16/04/2021 y lo que necesito es que me traiga el nombre del día en este caso JUEVES

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("yesterday"));
```

Comment: Leistes la documentacon de [date](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)? Ahi esta la respuesta

Comment: Es mas, ya lo tienes resuelto, solo es: `echo strftime("%A", strtotime("yesterday"))` ya que [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php) en su segundo parametro es un [timestamp](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php)

Comment: @JuanRivera Me da el dia de hoy y en ingles

Comment: Tienes que poner al comienzo: `setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish")`, para cambiar el idioma, como lo hicistes, luego el otro codigo que puse

Comment: @JuanRivera No logro que me de

Comment: Por lo visto, la funcion `setlocale` o no lo tienes activado o falta configurar para español en tu servidor php, pero para no hacer complicado el problema, ya te dieron la solucion usando arrays

Comment: @JuanRivera ya logre hacerlo , muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora como puedo evitar que el día no se cambie a las 6 si no hasta las 12:00pm

Answer (score 2):

[Documentación de la función date() php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

```
<?php

//parámetro l: Una representación textual completa del día de la semana (Sunday hasta Saturday)
date('l', strtotime("yesterday"))

//parámetro w: epresentación numérica del día de la semana (0 para domingo hasta 6 para sábado)
date('w', strtotime("yesterday"));



//Puedes hacer algo así:
$dias = array('Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado');

$dias[date('w', strtotime("yesterday"))];

?>
```